# How to remove the "vocals section" of an audio file in .NET?

Tags: .net, audio, standards

From an audio file (mp3 song) and I'm trying to extract the "instrument" part of the file to create a [minus one track](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3708/why-are-instrumental-tracks-also-called-minus-one-tracks).

How can this be done with .NET?

Is there any way to achieve something like this? :

```
new AudioFile("song.mp3").RemoveVocals().SaveTo("song edited.mp3")
```

Comment: @Rob: I imagine the downvotes are because removing vocals from a sound file is a very imprecise art; it's not something you can automate, and even doing it by hand you can't always get great results.  This is assuming, of course, the vocals aren't on a separate track (something I don't think the mp3 format supports).  Sorry, but you're not going to find a library that does this well.

Comment: This is a good question that is deserving of an answer. From the little that I recall from a speech processing class at college, the human voice operates at certain frequencies. A naive answer based on this understanding would involve removing all sounds within the range of these frequencies. Speech recognition uses statistical models like HMMs to improve accuracy but these require training. I'm sure there is a better explanation that can be by one of the experts on here.

Comment: @Brian Lyttle but wouldn't removing sounds from that frequency also remove any possible instruments that operate on those frequencies?

Comment: @Pacerier:  Yes, hence my comment that it doesn't lend itself well to automating.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft btw isn't there a way to encode the music into "sections" like 1 "section" for vocals and "1 section" for instruments..

Comment: Yes, I already mentioned separate tracks.  It needs to be encoded that way from the beginning though - if the vocals and music are on one combined track, there is no reliable way to separate them.  I don't know if MP3 supports separate tracks (other than left/right ear), or if it does, I have at least never seen a song which keeps its vocals and music on separate tracks - music and vocals are usually combined in the studio, before the song is released.

Comment: This question got closed, deleted, undeleted (with a vote from a diamond moderator), reopened (same diamond) and is being closed again. It was referenced on [a side issue on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306576/540552). Independent of showing recently deleted vs deleted recently, people who want this closed, could you argue about the question closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At my work we do a lot of media encoding type things in C# (Silverlight, to be specific).  We're in the middle of porting an application from Adobe Director to Silverlight, which means, of course, that all of the media we were using before (.ogg and .swf files in particular) no longer are compatible with our framework.  All of the cross encoding that we do happens outside of code, using third party tools.  If you are trying to do this on the fly, you're likely going to have to write it yourself.  If you want it done pre-runtime, I would start searching for utilities that do it.

Comment: Hello Eric! Could you please let me know which libraries are available to use to split MP3 file into acapella and vocal Thanks

Comment: I left the job I mentioned three years ago and was never deeply involved in the encoding work. TBH, I'm not sure why this was ever selected as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 10):

<sub>Synopsis of BlueRaja's useful comments below the question:</sub>

Music and vocals are usually combined in the studio before the song is released. If the vocals and music are on one combined track, there'll be no *reliable* way to separate them, since removing "vocal sounds" of a certain frequency will also end up removing "instrumental sounds" that happen to be in the same frequency. (read: sounds are sounds and "vocal" is a kind of "instrument".)

However, if the vocals and music are encoded on separate tracks, there'll be a way to separate them.

Comment: Hello @pacerier ! Could you please let me know which libraries are available to use to split MP3 file into acapella and vocal Thanks